# Should you define user-writable values as variables or options in Vim plugins?

Tags: vim

Should values that a Vim plugin allows users to set be defined as options or variables? I'm not quite sure what the difference is, or what the impact of using one over the other is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "options" you mean things like `autoindent` or `colorcolumn`, you can `set` or `unset` them and retrieve their value… but you *can't* create "options".

What you can use, though, are "internal variables" on which you can read all about in `:help internal-variables`.

Use global variables (`g:var`) for the user-defined "options" of your plugin and script-local variables (`s:var`) or function-local variables (`l:var` or simply `var` inside a function) in your script.

```
if !exists('g:myplugin_option')
    let g:myplugin_option = 1
endif
```

Comment: A non-scoped variable is global unless it is defined inside a function.  Try `:let foo=17 | echo g:foo`, for example.

Comment: @benjifisher, I know that, I assumed it would be used inside a function, here. I'll modify my answer to remove confusion.